# Facebook Friends Likes count for a page in html

Tags: html, angularjs, facebook, social-likes

I want To Display count that number of friends liked a page in html anyone please tell me 
and i know by using simple url we can get the page likes but i want know how to get the count of friends who liked a page and that too i want to use technologies only angularjs and html

Comment: Use the graph api. like `graph.facebook.com/cocacola`

Comment: i am new to Facebook APi can you Explain

Comment: if you are new to the facebook api, you need to start reading: https://developers.facebook.com/docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not directly possible (with just a link). You could use

```
GET /v2.3/{page-id}?fields=context.fields%28friends_who_like%29
```

but that requires that the friends give your app the permission to use their data.

You will then receive a `summary` field:

```
"summary": {
    "social_sentence": "4 of your friends like this.", 
    "total_count": 4
}
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page.context/friends_who_like